# Invalid Request Block Size with Nginx and USWGI

Tags: nginx, docker, python, docker-compose, uwsgi

I am trying to load balance 2 Python apps using Docker and Nginx.

App 1 is run using UWSGI and App 2 is run using default Python Server (I used default server for App 2 just for testing purposes. At the end of the day both should use UWSGI)

The hierarchy is as follows:

```
-app1
---app.py
---Dockerfile
---app.ini

-app2
---app.py
---Dockerfile

-nginx
---Dockerfile
---nginx.conf

-docker-compose.yml
```

app.py (for both app1 and app2 is the same)

```
from flask import request, Flask
import json

app1 = Flask(__name__)

@app1.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Salam alikom, this is App1 (App2 for app2) :)'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app1.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

app1/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
WORKDIR /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /
ENTRYPOINT ["uwsgi", "app.ini"]
```

app1/app.ini

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = app.py
callable = app
socket = :5000
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = true
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

app2/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
WORKDIR /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

nginx/nginx.conf

```
upstream loadbalancer {
    least_conn;
    server 192.168.100.2:9001;
    server 192.168.100.2:9002;
}
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    build: ./app1
    ports:
      - "9001:5000"
  app2:
    build: ./app2
    ports:
      - "9002:5000"
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "9003:80"
    depends_on:
      - app1
      - app2
```

When i run my docker compose file, containers for app 1, app 2 and the nginx server are created. When i access the load balancer on port 9003, only app 2 shows. When i manually go to port 9001, i get the error message `invalid request block size: 21573 (max 4096)...skip` for app 1.

If i use default Python server for app 1 too then the load balancing works fine but i don't want to use that since the default python server is only for development environment.

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar problem with the invalid block size, in my case it was preventing authentication happening to the app and giving a "502 Bad Gateway" error.

Anyway to cut a long story short I added the following line into my uwsgi.ini file

[uwsgi]
*stuff omitted for clarity*
**buffer-size = 8192**

Now by the sounds of things you are going to need to go up to 32,768 (32x1024), maybe even more. I was only a smidge outside (~5,000) of the default (4,096).

Hope that helps. Incidentally there is a bit more on the issue here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878176/uwsgi-invalid-request-block-size